# LoopBack 3 and SPA - where should I store the token?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, loopbackjs, loopback

I have some questions about the login process in **LoopBack 3** and modern **SPA**

1. The access token generated from **users/login** is **JWT**?
2. How to properly (safely) **store a token** generated from **users/login** on the modern **SPA side**? Just save them in localStorage or Cookies and after reading, attach them to API queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The accessToken generated by Loopback is not a JWT. It does not contain encrypted user data.
2. You could store it as a cookie on the browser and attach it to subsequent API queries.

Usually I use Redis to store my accesstokens so that the server can be stateless. This is a better solution if you have autoscaling configured.

Comment: Is there a way to configure Loopback 3 to generate JWT accessTokens?

Comment: You could try these packages - https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-jwt-advanced or https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-jwt. I dont work with Loopback anymore so my answer may not be the best. Please consider asking a separate question to get help from the wider community at Stackoverflow :)